# How to make an extjs grid a form field?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a requirement to create a custom form field that is basically an extjs grid. The user should be able to click a result in the grid. This clicked result should then become the fields value. Also, this field needs to extend Ext.form.field. Here's what I got:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.field.Grid', {
    alias: 'widget.GriedField',
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Base',
```

I'm a lot of confused on how to add a grid to form field base. Looks like form field base's template expects HTML. How do I get it accept a component?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to select a value from a list of items. Why not use a combobox?

If you need to select multiple items. There is an example of how to use the MultiSelect ux component in the documentation examples.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html

If you really must use a grid. Then I wouldn't bother with trying to create a field type and cause yourself grief.

Add a listener to your grids [selectionchange](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-selectionchange) event and update a [hidden](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Hidden) field in your form with the value you want from the grid. Job done.

Comment: And what about all the other nice things that come with having a form field; like a field label?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up putting the grid on a form indirectly through creation of dependencies on my model.

My model has master-detail, which the detail is just a store reference.  I found that using associations did not work for me.

So, in adding a field to a form, I have something that manages changed events for the model (master record) and the detail stores.